# How to handle my C++ program crash on a system w/o development IDE?

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I am testing my C++ app crash on a Windows 8 system that does not have development IDE installed (Visual Studio C++.) I was able to get the following from the Windows Event log:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: my_app_name.exe
P2: 1.0.2.0
P3: 4fffd4db
P4: my_app_name.exe
P5: 3.0.2.0
P6: 4fffd4db
P7: c0000005
P8: 00074eb0
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Windows\Temp\WER4AEB.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Windows\Temp\WER4B0B.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Windows\Temp\WER4B0C.tmp.hdmp
C:\Windows\Temp\WER4CD2.tmp.dmp

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_my_app_name.exe_8ea1c961fdc39248f2954cb7413ed349afffc9_cab_0d004d0d

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 4c93c3b5-ccc2-11e1-9b6e-000c297b96e1
Report Status: 4
Hashed bucket:
```

I was trying to go to those paths provided to get the .hdmp and .dmp files but there's nothing where it points in that report.

Any idea how to handle this situation?

Comment: Use logging to trace your application's behavior

Comment: You can't install windbg also?

Comment: It's a service that's crashing. Plus the system is not my computer and I don't feel comfortable installing too much on it... Only if I could get those dmp file I'd debug it on my IDE. I just don't know where those went since the crash?

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) service crashes should be written to %WINDIR%\System32\Config\SystemProfile not sure if this is still the same path for Win 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your service crash dumps maybe written to here:

```
%WINDIR%\System32\Config\SystemProfile
```

according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) not sure if this is still the same path for Win 8.

You can use [AdPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) or [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) or programmatically do this using [MiniDumpWriteMiniDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to write the memory dumps to a location of your choice, also [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163437.aspx) can be used for event tracing.

The dump files can be open in Visual studio or WinDbg and you can then look at the app state.

In WinDbg:

```
!analyze -v
```

will attempt to find the cause of the crash for you, hope this helps.

Comment: Windows Error Reporting (AKA WER) can be configured to save crash dumps in a specified location. I don't remember the details, but I've done it once on Windows 7.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze there is a link here for more:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487440.aspx but the OP is asking where the default location is, it sounds like Win8 has generated the dumps somewhere

Comment: AFAIR, Windows will save crash dumps (if generated) in some folder and then can delete them (perhaps, after they're sent to Microsoft?). I remember seeing phantom dumps prior to configuring WER properly (=as I wanted).

Comment: Thanks for the links. Yes, as long as I have the .hdmp and .dmp files I can recreate the crash with the VS IDE and the .pdb files that I kept. The issue is finding those. @AlexeyFrunze: It seems like Windows indeed collects the crash dumps and then purges them... although the purpose of doing it that way escapes me? And if they upload them to the MS servers, I can only imagine the size of those monsters -- can you imagine, every time something crashes on Windows.... man, even Google datacenters may be not big enough :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visual studio remote debugger tool (google it) to allow you to connect to a running proces via Visual Studio. Of course the machine must be on the same network.

1. Go to "Debug->Attach To Process".
2. Change Transport to "Remote"
3. Enter the IP of the target machine in "Qualifier"
4. Select the process to attach to.
5. Debug!

Also if you have crash dumps (.hdmp, .dmp... available at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\`) you can run them through WinDBG, which (if you have symbols and source code paths setup) will point you to a code line after you run the `!analyze -v` command. You do not need to have WinDBG on the target machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't able to find anything in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\ folder though.